# Request origin http://localhost:19006 does not have permission to access the resource

Tags: azure, security

when I want to test my Azure app function from http://localhost:19006, I have the error "Request origin http://localhost:19006 does not have permission to access the resource".
How can my azure app security be configured to allow my local url?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to disable CORS policy.
Can you check the link below. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29de3cb8-a55b-4fc7-98f6-53d139f8e7d2/disabling-azure-cors?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview